# Why ingressClassName disappears from Ingress configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have the following ingress configuration for my cluster:

```
# Source: ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-proxy-header: keep-alive
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-access-log: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      add_header X-Version 'latest';
      add_header X-Backend-Cache 'NO';
      add_header x-svc 'example-svc';
      expires -1;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 15m
  name: example
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - host: "example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example-svc
            port: 
              name: web
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: /example/v[0-9\\.]+/(.*)
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example-svc
            port: 
              name: web
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: /example/[a-z0-9]{40}/(.*)
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example-svc
            port: 
              name: web
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: /example/latest/(.*)
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example-svc
            port: 
              name: web
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: /example/(.*)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "example.com"
    secretName: "letsencrypt-example"
```

When it's applied using `helm upgrade --install` command, for some reason `ingressClassName: nginx` disappears from spec and this ingress doesn't work.

```
==> v1/Ingress
NAME                    CLASS   HOSTS                 ADDRESS         PORTS    AGE
example                 <none>  example.com           1.2.3.4         80, 443  1m
```

However, when I manually apply it with `kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml`, everything works as expected.

Can someone explain me why `ingressClassName` disappears from configuration?

It's worth mentioning that the same ingress configuration but with one path only works as well, so I assume that multiple paths can be the problem here.

In the cluster I have Helm v2.17.0 and Kubernetes v1.21 installed.

There is a corresponding IngressClass, `kubectl get IngressClass nginx -o yaml` gives me this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nginx-ingress
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: nginx-ingress
  creationTimestamp: "xxxxx"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.1
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.1.4
  name: nginx
  resourceVersion: "xxxxx"
  uid: xxxxx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
```

I also know about `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation but as long as it is deprecated I want to avoid using it.

Comment: Are you using a chart to deploy that and if so which one?

Comment: @rick-rackow I use my company's project chart that was written there.